# PHP Get content of another php page

Tags: php, html, include, shoutcast

I've got a webpage that display this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRQF2.jpg
Just plain text. And I need to include this in another php webpage, like

```
$string = include('http://77.144.233.158:4032/currentsong?sid=1');
echo $string;
```

so this can return "King crimson - Moonchild - Lyrics".
but this doesn't work.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) will **evaluate** what's inside the specified file (And run it as PHP). For example, if you had:

```
$str = 'King crimson - Moonchild - Lyrics';
```

You could include it, and then echo `$str` to get what you are looking for.

**I think what you're looking for is [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):**

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://77.144.233.158:4032/currentsong?sid=1');
echo $string;
```

From the docs:

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.